# GDB Hanging - Not understanding why

Tags: c, gdb

I'm going through the book "The C Programming Language" and doing all of the examples plus poking around in GDB to see what's going on.

In the below example code, the goal is to evaluate a few lines of text to determine which is the longest line. I thought my own program was failing because gdb was hanging at the for loop which calls `getchar()`. I followed the backtrace, found the culprit function, but couldn't determine the exact problem. Then I did the same with the example code, and the exact same problem occurs at the `for` loop which calls `getchar()`.

```
// file: ch1/ex16.c
// OBJECTIVE: Revise the main routine o the lnogest program
// so it will correctly print the length of arbitrarily long
// lines and as much as possible of the text.

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int getLine(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
  int len, max;
  char line[MAXLINE], longest [MAXLINE];

  max = 0;
  while ((len = getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
    if (len > max) {
      max = len;
      copy(longest, line);
    }
  }

  if (max > 0) {
    printf("%s", longest);
  }

  return 0;
}

int getLine(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c, i;

  for (i=0; i < lim - 1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
    s[i] = c;
  }
  if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
  }
  s[i] = '\0';

  return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
  int i = 0;

  while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0'){
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not to be a jerk but...while in GDB are you typing input for it to process and end the input with ^d or such?

Comment: Rename your `getline` to `mygetline`; it conflicts with the standard [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). Also run perhaps `gdb -tui` or `ddd` I suspect that you are confusing GDB and your program's *stdin* and *stdout*. Or run `gdb` under `emacs` using `M-x gdb`

Comment: Chris Hayes: Fixed.

@Duck: No, you weren't being a jerk at all :D This solves my problem. The way the program is written requires input from the command line. The fix was easy once you mentioned that. Ha, ha. 

(gdb) run < input.txt

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thanks for the input. I noticed that earlier when I first imported the sample code, so I changed the case in the example code from getline() to getLine(). Duck's comment enlightened me to the answer.

Comment: Okay, I know I'm a newbie, but I can't find the button or whatever that allows me to select my question as answered. :/

Comment: @trn450 You've probably figured this out, but now that you've self-answered, you'll be able to select your answer as the correct one after some period of time (I forget how long).

Comment: Yes, @ChrisHayes, I found that earlier. But, thank you for following up anyway.  I also didn't realize that a comment and an answer were distinct response types, so I couldn't select Duck's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike when executing the program through the shell, [gdb](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) wouldn't accept ^d (ctrl+d) as EOF. Thanks to the comment that Duck provided above, I found that if I fed it a file through standard input [gdb](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) it solved the problem.

Ex:

(gdb) run < file.txt